# Properly handling embedded images in Xamarin.Forms while using Live Player

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

Building and deploying on the real device takes ages. Xamarin Live Player is great and handy, but has some harsh [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=android). I want to use the [embedded images](https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#embedded-images) approach, that is working when the solution is built and deployed but falls into those limitations of the Live Player, and I am getting such exceptions:

```
[LogEntry: Time=2018. 05. 04. 9:42:31 +02:00, Level=Error, Title=Visualization Error, Message=Object of type 'NInterpret.InterpretedObject' doesn't match target type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IMarkupExtension' (TargetException)]
```

Is there any simple workaround to make the application show in Player? I could happily live with not showing the image at all (or at best showing a placeholder instead) when using Player and have the image shown as expected when using the regular flow.

Comment: Give a go to Gorilla Player instead.

Comment: @François Gorilla Player could give you an approach, is not perfect but at least render the biggest part of your controls. And doesn´t crash.

Comment: Thank you all. Gorilla Player is indeed much better!